# Windows thread impersonation is lost after log off / fast startup

Tags: windows, winapi, impersonation, security-context

There is a Windows service with a running thread that [impersonates](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/securitybaseapi/nf-securitybaseapi-impersonateloggedonuser) a security context of a [logged-on user](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/wtsapi32/nf-wtsapi32-wtsqueryusertoken). Then there is system shutdown -> [**fast startup**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/test/weg/delivering-a-great-startup-and-shutdown-experience#fast-startup) sequence that performs the user log off. After that the thread continues its execution but behaves weirdly, it seems the impersonation is lost and the thread security context is reverted to self.

[ImpersonateLoggedOnUser](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/securitybaseapi/nf-securitybaseapi-impersonateloggedonuser) documentation [says](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/securitybaseapi/nf-securitybaseapi-impersonateloggedonuser#remarks):

> *The impersonation lasts until the thread exits or until it calls RevertToSelf.*

There is nothing about log off or [fast startup](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/test/weg/delivering-a-great-startup-and-shutdown-experience#fast-startup) scenario.

I'm wondering if an access token and/or impersonation are invalidated when a user is logged-out? If so, are there any documentation links that describes that? Are there any workarounds to keep impersonation?

Comment: Confirmed from a Microsoft engineer, access tokens and impersonation are invalidated when a user is logged-out. The situation can be deduced from *ImpersonateLoggedOnUser* which lets the calling thread impersonate the security context of a **logged-on** user.